# what is the difference between jax-rpc(jsr224) and jax-ws(jsr101)

Tags: web-services, java, jsr

i just want to figure out how the two JSR difference, they are all used different way to implement the web service, one seems like using annotation, already included in jre1.6, the other is need to download some package axis, so i just think just two package to implement web serive or soap?

Comment: JAX-RS is initial version of specification. JAX-WS is latest with annotation support and lot other enhancements.

Comment: yes, and i also want to the relation with jax-rpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rpc is older, and implement webserive and client are both different, they are actually two different package